# Casting object from JSON to float

Tags: c#, json, casting

I came across a very strange thing when creating a JSON settings file in a project. globalSettings is a container that stores many settings.

In a property PreHeight I store the new value to the globalSetting (these settings will be persisted to a json file on application exit). I even explicitly cast "value" for clarity (not really required).

```
globalSettings["PreHeight"] = (float)value;
```

When I try to load the settings back at startup I first tried the following code.

```
   PreHeight = (float)globalSettings["PreHeight"];
```

To my surprise it throw an unable to cast exception. I then just changed the line to use the language neutral approach Convert.ToSingle(). In the background it should do exactly the same type of cast. To my surprise the code line does not throw when using the Convert.ToSingle() approach.

```
   PreHeight = Convert.ToSingle(globalSettings["PreHeight"]);
```

Can someone please explain this strange behavior?

I am well aware that JSON saves in the simplests data type, so a 0 is seen as an integer, but why on earth would it be a problem to cast it back to a float?

Comment: What library do you use? Will (float)globalSettings["PreHeight"].Value work? What is the value of globalSettings["PreHeight"]?

Comment: What JSON? What is `globalSettings`? How did you deserialize those settings into `globalSettings`?

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging my head, I arrive at a conclusion that your framework just returns an object (not a string or float).

Since it's not a string, Float. Parse fails.

Since it's an object, And CLR assumes it to be a Double Precision floating point (which is default), Typecast operator cannot convert it due to possible loss of precision. That's how typecast operator fails to work. The alternative code could be,

```
 PreHeight = (float) ((double)(globalSettings["PreHeight"]);
```

Convert.ToSingle is the guy meant to handle Double Precision to Single Precision conversion and It works well.

```
 PreHeight = Convert.ToSingle(globalSettings["PreHeight"]);
```

Is the only right to way to handle this conversion.

Comment: Ah okay so handles all value types as strings. Got it, it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Johan who handles them as strings? What is `globalSettings`? JSON.NET for example serialized and deserializes strongly-typed objects. You seem to be using a `Dictionary<string,string>` that was loaded by code you didn't post here

Comment: @CodeNameJack you didn't provide a real explanation, just a guess that `globalSettings` is a Dictionary<string,string>. That may or may *not* be true

Comment: true, My answer assumes there is no specific deserializer,
As in dot net core infact you call configuration.GetSection which will automatically desrialize the value.

Comment: @CodeNameJack in fact, you could rephrase it to `I don't know why it's a string, just parse it like you already do`

Comment: @CodeNameJack which uses Json.NET to *read* the settings. Not deserialize them. The settings may come from Ini files, databases, environment variables, the command line or JSON files.

Comment: jSon.NET is deserializer If I am not wrong, At least in the true sense of deserialization

Comment: I use https://github.com/Nucs/JsonSettings which is based on Newtonsoft.Json.
Float.Parse was not working by the way. It complained that it could not cast object to string when usíng that approach. Using Convert.ToSingle() seems to be the best solution.  Big question is just why.

Comment: Maybe it would be safer to use jsonNet?

Comment: Can you upload your settings class definition, at least with the float member being referred?
I read the source code, They just deserialize into the type being supplied for reading.

Comment: Also a sample value of the object.

Comment: Added possible explanation

Answer (score 0):

If the value returned by indexing `globalSettings` is a string, then casting `string` to `float` is not possible. `Convert.ToSingle` uses `Single.Parse` under the hood. That's why it works and that is also what you should use:

```
using System;

PreHeight = Single.Parse(globalSettings["PreHeight"]);
// or
PreHeight = float.Parse(globalSettings["PreHeight"]);
```